# How do I find out if my computer's hardware is compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, operating-systems, migration

I'm going to switch OS. From Windows 7 to Linux (Ubuntu, I think). Problem is that I'm not sure about my computer's hardware. Will it be suitable and there will be working drivers for it? For example, I have an external WiFi receiver that I use with Windows.

I thought I'd look for some command or application that prints out info about my hardware (on Windows 7, at the moment).

> Is my hardware suitable for Ubuntu?
>
> Here is the list:
>
> ...

I hope that you can help me.

Comment: No need to go to a different site, your question is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: I think that you are ok with respect to what site that you are on. I do think that the question is still a little ambiguous. What information about your hardware specifically are you looking for?

Comment: @slhck Yay then. :)

Comment: @EBGreen Probably everything that Ubuntu will not be compatible with. But my guess is that 99% will be. The only hardware I can imagine not being compatible would be some external devices -- and for finding out those you don't need software.

Comment: @EBGreen All that is required to clarify... does my hardware will be suitable for Ubuntu (inluding drivers). In my opinion, first thing will be the model.

Comment: @slhck I have one external device. I'm worried about it too! Its my wi-fi receiver. Without it... no internet for me. How to find out info about it again?

Comment: @daGrevis I changed the title of your question because that's your *real* problem. Is that ok?

Comment: @slhck Ye, no problems. One little thingy: I'm not native English speaker, but isn't that in headings all words must start with a capital letter (except those little ones like "to", "the" etc.)?

Comment: @daGrevis They don't have to, but it's valid too :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux kernel supports a vast range of hardware. Of course, some things are better supported than others. Chances are your machine should run alright regardless. If you've got atypical hardware, or a strange environment, then that could add complexity. I've found some wireless network cards are still not well supported and getting great video performance is fairly dependent on your video card as some modern cards can require some work to get running and others work with next to no thought.

**Your best quick test is to download and burn the Ubuntu installation CD. Then boot up the Live version of it from disc.** This doesn't touch your hard drive. If it runs off CD fairly well, then you should expect it'll run off your hard drive reasonably well should you install it to.

Alternatively, you can go do a bunch of research in to supported hardware. But just trying it is a good option in your case I think.

Comment: Was gonna suggest the same. Related Ubuntu article: [Checking hardware compatibility](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/switching/preparing-hardware.html) says, "The easiest way to check whether your hardware is compatible with Ubuntu is to make use of the Ubuntu Desktop CD"

Comment: Hmmm... I did that already (installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox). Internet worked. All worked. But... I did install Ubuntu as my primary OS too (few months ago); before I did format my hard drive. Then, unexpected, internet didn't work. Dilemma!

Comment: how can you test the video graphics driver this way? don't you have to reboot?

Comment: Wait, you speak about Live CD not VirtualBox? Great idea! Gonna check. If there will be problems... I will be back.

Comment: @daGrevis: Running Ubuntu from within a VM won't at all test how it'll run natively on your hardware. The VM Host environment provides well known virtual hardware that will certainly work. Ubuntu 11.04 was released about 2 months back (at the very end of April).. So maybe you didn't try that version. Regardless, I suggest you just try it from the CD.

Comment: LiveCD's a good route..  Another option is to use the Wubi installer from the CD from within Windows - this installs Ubuntu in way that it can be uninstalled from the "Add/Remove Programs" tool in Windows - which is a handy way to partly commit but have a simple path back to only running Windoze.